# How to retrieve the contents of a text area where the contents are not represented under the html code

Tags: java, selenium

I have a text area where the the contents are not represented under the HTML code.
The code looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Ping Results</legend>
<textarea id="displayArea" cols="80" rows="10" name="displayArea"></textarea>
<table class="content-form" summary="Layout: Ping Results">
<tbody>
<tr> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Upon clicking a button on the UI, the contents appear in the text area.

like:
PING 10.106.214.55 (10.106.214.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.106.214.55: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms

--- 10.106.214.55 ping statistics ---
 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
 rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.072/0.072/0.072/0.000 ms

I have tried:

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("displayArea"));
String text = ele.getAttribute("value");

and getText() as well.
Both return nothing.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We can access inbuilt **value** attribute to get the value typed in TextArea. Code is written below:

```
String value = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", driver.findElement(By.id("displayArea"))).toString();
```

Lemme know if this helps!

Comment: Hi mfsi_sitamj,   Using the above line of code I am getting the method executescript is undefined for the type WebDriver.please suggest.